# Constructing Bode plot from experimental data and constructing a transfer function

Tags: transfer-function, bode-plot

I've been trying for a few days to **convert** an **experimentally obtained** (frequency against magnitude and frequency against phase) **graphs** to a **Bode plot** and then **construct a transfer function** from  the Bode plot

[image]

I constructed a table:

1. Converted each frequency from Hertz to rad/s by multiplying it by \$2\pi\$
2. Converted each magnitude to dB by multiplying it by \$20\log(\text{magnitude})\$

**Note: As seen in the original graph, all the magnitudes are negative. When converting to dB, you cannot take the log of a negative number so I assumed it to be positive. Am I correct? Will this affect my Bode plot?**

The table can be seen below:

[image]

Then I plotted the Bode plot below:
[image]

I understand that my transfer function will be a first order because the phase shifts 90 degrees meaning the highest power of the denominator will be 1. In other words, there will be 1 pole in the denominator.

In summary, my questions:

1. **Was I correct in converting the negative magnitude to db by ignoring the negative value?**
2. **What will be the final transfer function of the constructed Bode plot?**

Comment: Have you considered covering a wider range of frequency? over just 15:1, are you sure about those asymptotes? this looks like a pole (roll off, or drop in gain), followed by a zero (a rise in gain) used to flatted out the pole. Here the flattening is done at a higher frequency.

Comment: You already have it plotted in dB, so there was no need for conversion. By the looks of it, since you are starting your phase at around 0, then go to -90, you are missing a decade of critical information.

Comment: @analogsystemsrf Thanks for the reply, the frequency range measured (from 0.1-1.6hz) was a requirement given from the lab. From my knowledge, I understand that we have 1 pole and 1 zero like you mentioned. But they need to rise by 20db/dec but our experimentally measured data takes more than a decade to rise up to 20db. What do you recommend I do? Shall I make assumptions?

Comment: The pole interacts with the ZERO. You are using just 2 resistors and 2 capacitors, right?

Comment: Hi there. I realised I made a slight mistake in my question and corrected it. The system is indeed a first order system hence why the phase shifts to -90.  May I ask if there is a possible way to make an asymptotic bode diagram from the accurate one I have constructed? Also you were correct. I need to inverse all my gain values to make the graph like how u have stated in the answer. May I also ask what makes the phase go to -90 and then back to zero? or is that because I previously stated that the system was a second order? thanks

Comment: Also, Im not sure about the resistors and capacitors. Because this was an open loop experiment done at the lab using a Feedback instrument servo system.

Comment: Given the original magnitude data starts WITH A TILT, that is, non-flat and thus is not asymptotic, the lower end of the needed data is missing. Ditto for the phase data. Can you acquire mag/phase from 0.01 or 0.025?

Comment: you have no data ABOVE 1.5, correct. Thus to **draw** a flat line above 1.5 is very misleading. Please correct that plot. ----------------- GIven the plots provide NO asymptotes, you can only judge the F3dB from the 45 degree point. What frequency is that?

Answer (score -2):

I would draw a combined POLE_ZERO response like this, which assumes only 2 resistors and 2 capacitors. The interaction prevents reaching the 10:1 attenuation effect.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIUfQK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Can you explain **why** you chose this representation? It doesn't appear to be consistent with the data provided by the OP. Can you add values to the axes? As it is, this answer doesn't seem to be helpful, particularly to someone coming along later with a similar, but not identical, problem.

Comment: This is the response of a pole interacting with a zero. I've asked the OP for explanation. Is this being helpful to you? Then upvote my comment.

Comment: Can you explain how you determined that there was one pole and one zero, based on the information provided by the OP? The OP appears to be unclear about why there must be a zero and what affect that has on the Bode plot. Can you explain how the locations of the pole and zero are related to the shape of the graphs? Can you label the axes?

Comment: I see NO phase curves in the plots, on my computer. I just examined the rising gain response, noticing the leveling off. That behavior comes from a zero followed by a pole. However, the OP wrote of **negating** some values, meaning the gain (dB) response would be a falling response; if a falling response, this would be pole-followed-by-a-zero, Again, I saw no phase plot in the original question.